# Asp.net core web api calling Use() extension method for simple middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to add simple test middleware in Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next)=>{
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Middleware Test");
                await next.Invoke();
            });
         }
```

but I'm getting error on `next.Invoke()`:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HM0HT4E56F31", Request id "0HM0HT4E56F31:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
>   application. System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be
>   set because the response has already started.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.b__2()
>   at MiddlewareWebApiTest.Startup.<>c.<b__5_0>d.MoveNext() in
>   E:\vscode\MiddlewareWebApiTest\Startup.cs:line 44
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
>   application)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this your entire middleware pipeline? The whole `Configure` method?

Comment: I ask the because this code won't throw any errors. If you want to write to the response like this, you can't let any subsequent middleware in your pipeline set the status code. I assume you have MVC later down the code that you are not showing us.

Comment: yeah, I have and I want the flow pass through the middleware.  It's just for testing and understanding middleware principles. I tried both with or without subsequent builtin middlewares. It anyway throws that error in output

Comment: if I don't use another builtin middlewares, I mean if my entire pipeline would be just this what I have in Configure method, I should get as response "Middleware Test" right? but I am not getting anything but error like I described above

Comment: I used your code to test in my api project, everything is running normally, the page returns "Middleware Test". What version are you currently using? I suggest you provide more code or build a new project and retest.